# Java overall arrays limit?

Tags: java, arrays, storing-information

I am implementing a program that has about 2,000,000 (2 million) arrays each of size 16,512 (128 x 129) of integers. I only need to call 200 arrays at a time (that is 3.3 MB), but I wonder if I can expand the program to have more than 2 million (say 200 million) but I still only need to call 200 arrays at a time. So what is the limit of making more and more arrays while I don't use more than 200 arrays at a time?

Comment: I strongly suspect that your program design could use some refinement.

Comment: Why don't you just write a test program, where you can increase the number with command line args?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly doubt that, unless you're running on a 64 bit machine with a lot of RAM and a very generous heap.

Let's calculate the memory you'll need for your data:

```
2,000,000*128*129*8/1024/1024/1024 = 30.8GB.
```

You'll need additional RAM for the JVM, the rest of your program, and the operating system.

Sounds like a poorly conceived solution to me.

If you mean "I only have 200 arrays in memory at a time" you can certainly do that, but you'll have to move the rest out to secondary storage or a relational database.  Query for them, use them, GC them.  It might not be the best solution, but it's hard to tell based on the little you've posted.

Update:

Does "trigger" mean "database trigger"?

Yes, you can store them on the disk.   I can't guarantee that it'll perform.  Your hard drive can certainly handle 30GB of data; it's feasible that it'll accomodate 300GB if it's large enough.

Just remember that you have to think about how you'll manage RAM.  GC thrashing might be a problem.  A good caching solution might be your friend here.  Don't write one yourself.

What happens if that hard drive fails and you lose all that data?  Do you back it up?  Can your app afford to be down if the disk fails?  Think about those scenarios, too.  Good luck.

Comment: I don't have 30 GB of RAM I have 3GB.

I have 200 mobile nodes, each has 10k arrays of size int 128*129. 

each time slot all nodes (200) will get a value out of one array of each. 200 arrays will be used to retrieve one value for each node. the next time slot each node use a different array to retrieve a new value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do the other (2M minus 200) arrays live when you aren't using them?  And how do you get just the ones you need when you need them?

Comment: You are trying more memory than you have. You either have to buy more memory, or reduce your memory requirement.

Comment: I have a list of triggers (for each node) each trigger points to the array of interest . When the trigger occurs, the related array is retrieved, then the value of interest is retrieved, and the array is done for now until the trigger occurs again. Can't I store arrays on the hard disk and retrieve them when I need them?

Comment: @ duffymo : no trigger means when something happens to the node in my scenario, the trigger decides the array of interest which is related that event, restore it, get some value then the array is not needed till the even occurs again. 

I already made the program not to use more than 200 arrays at a time, but I forgot about arrays which are not in use. Actually it's an artificial intelligent car which will have to run for 1 week, using those arrays. I don't care if retrieving arrays from HD would take a little longer, but how long ?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't keep references to arrays you no longer need, there is no hard limit. Old arrays will automatically get garbage collected, so you can keep allocating and abandoning arrays pretty much ad infinitum.

There is, of course, a limit on how many arrays you can keep around at any given time. This is limited by the amount of memory available to the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you increase max heap size to make sure your application doesn't run out of memory, you shuold be fine.